# Install .NET 4.0 offline on Windows 8.1 and/or 10

Tags: .net, installation, offline

Currently, I am creating an installer for a .NET application which requires .NET 3.5 and 4.0. The requirement is also that the setup should install everything needed in the absence of Internet connectivity.

.NET 3.5 can be installed in offline mode as a Windows feature by using DISM (Microsoft's **D**eployment **I**mage **S**ervicing and **M**anagement tool) and by redistributing the .NET 3.5's cabinet (`.cab`) file from a Windows 8.1 or 10 installation DVD located at `<drive_letter>:\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab` as part of the application installer setup. There is a 32-bit version of the `.cab` file that is ~37 MB large and a 64-bit one sized ~69.1 MB. These `.cab`'s should be used for installing .NET 3.5 as a Windows feature in offline mode when the Windows OS version at hand is 8.1 or 10. Windows 7 has the .NET 3.5 installer files integrated and one should just issue the DISM command-line instruction to enable .NET 3.5 as Windows feature. To trigger the .NET 3.5 offline installation using this approach either of the following command-line statements could be used:

`dism /Online /Quiet /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /LimitAccess /Source:<dot_net_35_cab_file_dir_path>`

or

`dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:<dot_net_35_cab_file_path>`

Both of these statements are applicable only to Windows 8.1 and 10, since the DISM tool there is updated compared to its Windows 7 version. If the latter is the Windows OS version at hand, the command should be issued as follows:

`dism /Online /Quiet /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3`

This is much more efficient way to install .NET 3.5 instead of integrating the humongous [.NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 offline installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150) (sized ~231 MB) in the target application's installer.

**The problem:** First tried installing the [standalone .NET 4.0 setup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718) installing on all the three Windows OS versions: 7, 8.1, 10. It succeeded on 7 but Windows 8.1 and 10 reported the following error:
[image]

The .NET 4.0 setup reported this error even without already having installed any version of .NET 4.x either as a Windows feature or using a standalone installer:[image]

As obvious from the contents of the "Windows Features" dialog in the last cited screenshot taken in Windows 8.1 environment, .NET 4.x is available as a Windows feature but there is no `.cab` file in either Windows 8.1 or 10's installer DVD for it or I haven't found such by far. Presumably, the error above is output since there is a .NET > 4.0 on the current workstation as a Windows feature, no matter if it is disabled (unchecked) or not.

**The question:** could you tell me how exactly to deploy/redistribute .NET 4.0 on Windows 8.1 or 10 using an offline installer, or possibly a `.cab` file, `.wim` file, etc. in the absence of any Internet connectivity. There is very scarce and hard to find information as a result from Googling this problem or I am not searching for the right thing.

Comment: .NET 4.5 is pre-installed on Windows 8.1, 4.6 on Win10.  You only get to add "advanced services" with that checkbox.  So you must stop bothering.

Comment: Disagree. Ticking this checkbox without ticking the child checkboxes (the main checkbox is put in intermediate state) installs the base .NET 3.5/4.5/4.6 version. The advaced services you are talking about could be installed additionally by ticking either of those child checkboxes or fully checking the given .NET version main checkbox. But no matter if it comes preinstalled, one could disable the required .NET versions even if they are pre-installed Windows features. Thus the target application's installer should take care to install the needed .NET versions.